# svn add ip host

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Is it possible to add in svn as one field/column/atrribute more ( TortoiseSVN ), the IP that the commit of the source came ?
so after the username and the path and the rest come the IP itself. Or better the name of the host ?

Comment: I don't think there is such thing. I have tried to find information in the [SVN Red Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn-book.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks) about repository hooks, but there is no hook that allows to do that, and even the information about the IP of the client is not available.

Comment: yes, I and this would be a trivial information. I had the case, remembering the PC's last code effort, a second PC's other effort, a join in parts of code in svn, and forgetting from what pc was the last commit in the svn, and after a weekend, which one is more recent.